# Error while importing sbt project: string.class is broken

Tags: java

Using the sbt tool I created a new project. I imported the project into Intellij. Then when I try to add the plugin PlayEbean I get this error:

```
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken.
```

Here's the whole error, kinda long so I didn't wanna post it here https://pastebin.com/embed_js/ekPN4nFv

Anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Here's the plugins.sbt file:

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.3")

// Defines scaffolding (found under .g8 folder)
// http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/scaffolding.html
// sbt "g8Scaffold form"
addSbtPlugin("org.foundweekends.giter8" % "sbt-giter8-scaffold" % "0.11.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.0")
```

Here's the build.sbt file:

```
name := """consulting-services-inc"""
organization := "com.myName"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += javaCore
```

Comment: Fix you dependencies first: `com.typesafe.play#play-ebean_2.13;5.0.0: not found`

Comment: playframework.com tells me to add addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "5.0.0") to the plugins.sbt file, which I did. Maybe this error I'm getting is why it's not found?

Comment: Add both the plugins.sbt & build.sbt file to your question (or link them externally if its too large)

Comment: ok, I added them in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a mismatch in the versions.

5.0.2 should work with scala 2.13, 5.0.0 apparently not.

Check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-ebean